# Why doesn’t Rust have reverse indexing / indexing from end for arrays?

Tags: arrays, rust

Since the size of array types in Rust are already known at compile-time, I was wondering what might be the reason for not having reverse indexing? By reverse indexing, I mean `arr[-1]` to access the last element of array `arr`

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://internals.rust-lang.org

Comment: I somewhat agree with the points mentioned in maxy's answer, but I just wanted to point out that it's not hard to create a wrapper that does support reverse indexing by yourself, if you really want that: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=170a5bd1fb12988563a2617ccdb2fbac

Comment: In addition to the reasons in the answers: perhaps the reverse/negative indexing simply wasn't well-known or "obvious" to Rust authors at the time Rust's basics were designed. Before the popularization of Python, I'm pretty sure most people would be unfamiliar with negative indexing - it's not supported by other mainstream languages like Java or C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of several reasons:

- If you calculate the index, you can easily calculate a negative index by mistake. This would not be a memory-safety issue in Rust, but bounds-checking would no longer work reliably. This would make a common class of bugs impossible to detect at run-time.
- It would have a run-time cost (it needs an addition, at least, compared to bounds-checking). It would be generating machine code that isn't needed in most cases, hurting performance.
- Arrays may have a known size at compile-time, reducing the cost, but slices do not. Surely you'd want indexing to mean the same for both slices and arrays.
- `arr[-1]` implies that the index is signed, so if you have a pointer you can use indexing only to access half of the possible memory range. This  can be a problem in systems programming where the highest memory bit may have a special meaning.
- Also, in C++ mixing signed and unsigned integers has a long history of pain and bugs. I'm not sure if this reasoning applies here, but at least many would feel better to avoid mixing signed and unsigned types whenever possible. (E.g. it requires care to compare those types with correct overflow handling.)

Comment: @FZs probably because using something like `arr[p-q]`, with a mistake in the values of `p` and `q`, could lead to indexing from the end even if it was absolutely not our intention and the correct behaviour would have been a `panic!()` in order to detect the error as soon as possible.

Comment: @prog-fh Oh, I see. I did consider this case as a reason not to have negative indexing, but I misunderstood what they were saying.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement it yourself if you want to.

```rust
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

pub struct ReverseIndex(pub usize);

impl<T> Index<ReverseIndex> for [T] {
    type Output = T;
    
    fn index(&self, idx: ReverseIndex)->&T{
        let len = self.len();
        &self[len - 1 - idx.0]
    }
}

impl<T> IndexMut<ReverseIndex> for [T] {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, idx: ReverseIndex)->&mut T{
        let len = self.len();
        &mut self[len - 1 - idx.0]
    }
}


fn main(){
    let g = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    assert_eq!(g[ReverseIndex(1)], 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since reverse indexing is often required, it's best to use a macro to avoid calculation errors.

```
macro_rules! rget {
    ($arr: expr, $idx: expr) => {{
        let len = $arr.len();
        if len > $idx {  // prevent overflow
            $arr.get(len - $idx - 1)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }};
}
```

Negative `usize` values are not allowed, so `arr[-1]` will never be implemented in Rust.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2bb433100b862da29118cbdb3d9b0eb4)